# How to implement fuzzy search in multi fields

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I was implementing fuzzy search in my existing elasticsearch where I can't change mappings, I was hoping if there is any way I can convert the following query in fuzzy one i.e add fuzzy search on fields **lower_name and album**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user": "userId"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "lower_name": ["search", "Text"]
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "album": ["search","Text"]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried this :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user": "userId"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "fuzzy": {
                  "lower_name": ["search","Text"]
                }
              },
              {
                "fuzzy": {
                  "album": ["search","Text"]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But this is giving error: **[fuzzy] query doesn't support multiple fields**
Please help!
Using Elasticsearch 6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [multi_match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) with fuzziness. Try out the below query

Index Data:

```
{
  "user": "ben",
  "lower_name": "def",
  "album": "Brenda"
}
{
  "user": "ben",
  "lower_name": "abc",
  "album": "Brenda"
},
{
  "user": "ben",
  "lower_name": "fgh",
  "album": "honda"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
     {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user": "ben"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "abc dey",
                  "fields": [
                    "lower_name"
                  ],
                  "fuzziness": "auto"
                }
              },
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "brenda",
                  "fields": [
                    "album"
                  ],
                  "fuzziness": "auto"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66311552",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.7497801,
        "_source": {
          "user": "ben",
          "lower_name": "def",
          "album": "Brenda"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66311552",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.7497801,
        "_source": {
          "user": "ben",
          "lower_name": "abc",
          "album": "Brenda"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I am using terms query over an array of search texts, I edited the question, please have a look at it again.

Comment: @RaghuChahar please go through the updated answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: It seems to work now, actually I had to use a keyword analyzer with this at search time to mock my previous flow.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use the `"fuzziness": "AUTO"`. param in your search query. [Refer fuzziness in match query official example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-fuzziness)

Comment: I am using terms query over an array of search texts, I edited the question, please have a look at it again.